# signature of public member contains native type

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am new to visual c++, I have the following code:

```
ref class Book sealed
{
public:
    Book(std::string title,std::string author,int year);
    void setTitle(std::string title);
    std::string getTitle() const;
    int getYear() const;
    void setYear(int year);
    void setAuthor(std::string author_);
    std::string getAuthor() const;

private:
    std::string title_;
    std::string author_;
    int year_;

};
```

When I am trying to compile it I am getting the following error:

`{ctor} signature of public member contains native type`. I suppose this is because I am using an the std::string and not the Platform::String, how can I fix that?

Comment: This doesn't look like C++. I think you need another language tag.

Comment: This is managed C++, not C++

Comment: @DavidKernin sorry, my mistake.

Comment: It's [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), Microsoft's adaptation of C++ for the .NET platform.  It's not standard C++.

Comment: No, it permits this.  This is C++/CX, a language extension that permits languages like VB.NET and Javascript to directly call C++ code.  Which of course cannot work with std::string, Javascript knows beans about that C++ class.

Answer (score 8):

Your ref class is not marked public itself, so it appears you are only consuming this class internally (as source) from other C++, and not intending for it to be published to other WinRT  consumers.

If this is the case, you can set your constructor as `internal` instead of `public`, which will be public within this component and not visible externally. And really if that's your intended usage, then it can just be a regular 'class' instead of a 'ref class'.  If you do wish to use it across the WinRT boundary but you don't need the constructor, you can make it a 'public ref class' and have the constructor marked as 'internal'.  Kinda depends on your scenario.

If you instead wish to make this class public **and** have a public constructor which is usable across the WinRT boundary (so that it can be consumed by C#/VB/JS), then you need to use WinRT types (such as `Platform::String`).  Within your class the storage type can still be a `std::string` (although I recommend using std::wstring, otherwise you need to do wide-to-narrow conversions, as Platform::Strings are wide strings).

To convert between these two types, use `Platform::String::Data()` to get at the underlying `wchar_t*` which you can use to construct a `std::wstring`.  And similarly, `Platform::String` has a constructor which takes a `wchar_t*` (which you can get from `std::wstring::c_str()`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't hold native types in a managed reference class.

You can only hold a pointer to an unmanaged object(a pointer is just a number after all, and that's why it's allowed).